# How to prevent the loss of messages sent by publisher (due to delay in pub sub connection), without using sleep method,in extended PUB-SUB topology?

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe, distributed-system

So I am implementing the extended **`PUB/SUB`** topology in ZeroMQ with c++.

I have 2 publishers, 1 intermediary ( a forwarder/proxy ), and 2 subscribers.

I call a **`sleep(1)`** method before calling a **`send()`** in the publishers.

But according to documentation, it is not an elegant way of synchronizing the publishers with the subscribers. The documentation provides a solution in which we create **`REQ`** and **`REP`** socket in a **`SUB`** and a **`PUB`** respectively. But this is difficult if there are multiple publishers and subscribers.

Please suggest how to prevent loss of messages in the extended **`PUB-SUB`** topology.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want guaranteed delivery from all publishers to all subscribes? What happens if one subscribes slows down? What happens if a publisher dies? What happens if the intermediary dies? The ZeroMQ guide has a full chapter on reliable pub/sub: http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5.

Comment: @jens .The aim is to ensure that all messages sent out by publishers , reach the subscribers. To do that I call sleep(1) before send in publishers, and also run the subscribers before publisher. But I am looking for a better solution than using sleep(). Assume that my publisher and intermediary don't die, and subscribers don't slow down.

Comment: If you are just concerned about message loss during the connection phase of the subscribes you would be better off with an explicit form of synchronization. This needs a back-channel from the subscribes to the publishes, e.g. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Node-Coordination. If you want guaranteed delivery in all cases you need to define a protocol on top of pub/sub that e.g. resends messages when needed. This can be similar to what TCP does. The guide should contain examples for that too. Or you extend your forward proxy to handle the subscribes, turning it into a persistent broker.

Comment: It would probably be better if you edited the question to contain more information, e.g. that you don't care about slow subscribers, connection loss, dying intermediates etc. I guess you are referring to the message loss because of the connect and subscribe delay, but you should add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes,
<sub>the known ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero does not warrant all messages to get it through ,</sub>

this means one can but ignore this part, as it is a principal feature of the system design.

---

**Yes**,
 **`REQ/REP`** or other, more complex "*augmented*"-composition of trivial primitive Scalable Formal Communication Archetype pattern built-ins, can help cope with the built-in design properties, yet all such steps are principally the application designer's responsibility to define, analyse and implement. Do not expect any magic wand, yet all these are common aspect, to one will [**find** a lot of examples **discussed here**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) already.